# Submit values from an Dynamic Form, Using Arrays

Tags: php, sql, arrays, forms

I have been trying to create a dynamic To-DO Template list, with preassigned items, descriptions, etc. The idea is to pull a template list from a table that will change from time to time. From there the user will uncheck to-dos from the template task list that they don't need to be inserted into another list or "TABLE".

---

| EXAMPLE |

TaskName = "Do Homework" TaskDescription = "Do Schoolwork at home" AsssignedTo = "Greg"

TaskName = "Workout" TaskDescription = "Go To Gym" AsssignedTo = "Greg"

---

If the above task is unchecked, then insert into "todos" table the following rows" except the one that isn't checked.

```
INSERT INTO todos (todo_name, todo_description,todo_assigned) Values (:taskname,:taskdecription, :taskassigned)
```

I have tried

```
<input type="checkbox" value=task[taskname][taskdesc] checked>
```

Start of my code.

```
<?php
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM plan_list');
$stmt->execute();$count = $stmt->rowCount();
?>

<form method="post" action="insert_list_tasks.php">
```

Pull Template List

```
<? 
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) 
{   
$name= $row['plan_name']
$desc= $row['plan_desc']
$assigned= $row['plan_assigned']
echo "<input type='checkbox'value='task[".$name."][".$desc."][".$assigned."]' name='id[]'checked>".$name."<br>";    
}
?>
<button>Add List To My ToDOs</button>
</form>
```

Not sure if I'm doing the value arrays correctly. This is where I'm stuck, inserting tasks into TODOs table.

```
<?php   
$stmt_insert = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO todos 
(todo_name, todo_assigned) Values (:plan_name, :plan_assigned)");

$stmt_insert->bindParam(':plan_name', $plan_name);
$stmt_insert->bindParam(':plan_assigned', $plan_assigned);
$stmt_insert->execute();

?>
```

Im expecting to get multiple values from the same checkbox input, but so far I have only been able to get 1, or it just echos "Array". At this point, I feel pretty dumb.

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Wherre is your code that uses `$_POST['id']`? It's an array, you need to loop over it.

Comment: `$name`, `$desc`, and `$assigned` are all the same column from the table. That doesn't seem right.

Comment: @Barmar Good Catch! I didn't see that when I was formatting it for stack. Just edited it. I know I have to use $_POST, but not sure on how to go about with the loop and assigning the values out. Should I use "While" or "Foreach"?

Comment: `foreach ($_POST['id'] as $id)`

Comment: Instead of putting all the columns in the checkbox values, I suggest you just put the primary key of the row. When you're processing the form, The `todos` table should contain a foreign key to `plan_tasks`, rather than duplicating columns.

Comment: @Barmar Thank! This got me on the right path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with code similar to this.

```
$todo_toaddornot = $_POST['toaddornot'];
$value1 =$_POST['value1'];
$value2 =$_POST['value2'];
for($i=0;$i<count($todo_name);$i++)
        {   //If Mark Yes Then Show
        if($todo_toaddornot[$i]==='Yes')
        { echo $value1[$i]; echo $value2[$i]; }}
```